# HTML submit button is not working in Typescript project

Tags: html, typescript, submit

iam working on a form, when submit data should be send to my email. simple HTML web page doing this successfuly.
but when i put this code to typescript project the submit button of form is not working. any one help please.

```
<form>
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
<span class="message"></span>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name..'>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder='Email..'>
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder='Message..'></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script>

let url = "url of google app script function";
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let submit = document.querySelector(".submit");
let message = document.querySelector(".message");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    submit.value = "submitting..."
    fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: new FormData(form)
        })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(data => {
            message.innerHTML = data;
            submit.value = "submit"

        })
        .catch(err => {
            message.innerHTML = err;
            submit.value = "submit"
        })
})

</script>`
```

i have tried html web page this working well. but in typescript project this is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You're also not using any Typescript in your code - just Javascript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.